# How do I change the colour of 2 cells when today’s date is reached in one of them

Tags: excel, date, colors

I have an excel sheet where I have names of people in one column and in the next the date they passed an induction.
How can I change the colour of both the name and the date when 12 months has passed (ie. 12 month renewal date)

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Conditional Formatting:

Select the top cells of the 2 columns you wish to format.

Conditional Formatting >> New Rule

Use a Formula to determine which cells to format:

(Assuming B2 is your Date field - edit as required)

```
=TODAY()>EDATE($B2,12)
```

Copy and paste (just the formula) over the other cells.

=TODAY()>EDATE($B2,12) takes TODAY, compares against your date value in your cell and returns TRUE if your cell date value is over 12 months old, or FALSE if less than 12 months old.